# Convergence of measure function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mathcal X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f, f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$ measurble functions.

How can one show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a. e. if for all $\epsilon > 0$ it holds true that

$\mu ( \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} \cup_{m \geq n}$ {$x: |f_m - f(x) | \geq \epsilon $}$) = 0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B:=\{x\in \chi\ |\ \{f_n(x)\}_n\ \text{ converges to }f(x)\}$. Then

> $$B^c=\bigcup_{m≥1}\ \bigcap_{n≥1}\  \bigcup_{i≥n} \ \bigg\{x\in \chi\ :\
>  |f_i(x)-f(x)|≥\frac{1}{m}\bigg\}$$

To prove this let $x\in B^c$ then the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ does not converge to $f(x)$, so there is $m\in \Bbb N$ such that for each $n\in \Bbb N$ we have some $i\geq n$ with $|f_i(x)-f(x)|≥\frac{1}{m}$. So $x$ belongs to the set of right hand side.

Conversely if $x$ is in set of right hand side then for some $m_0\in \Bbb N$ and for all $n\in \Bbb N$ we have some positive integers $i_n≥n$ such that $|f_{i_n}(x)-f(x)|≥\frac{1}{m_0}$ i.e. $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ does not converge to $f(x)$. Hence such $x$ obviously is in $B^c$.

Now, $B^c$ has zero measure implies $\forall m\in \Bbb N$ we have, $
\bigcap_{n≥1}\  \bigcup_{i≥n} \ \big\{x\in \chi\ :\
 |f_i(x)-f(x)|≥\frac{1}{m}\big\}$ has measure zero. So we are done.